# zend frame work in server as a centralized one to all my websites

Tags: zend-framework

Our team is using php zend frame work for the development of websites

every time we deployed it takes lot of memory in server

using zend we developed almost 9 sites.

what my Question is it possible to place the zend frame work in server as a centralized one to all my websites

please help us....

Comment: How to install ZF on server:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306817/zend-configuration-on-ubuntu/14355158#14355158

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to have the Zend Framework Library in one location but available to multiple applications (websites).

If this is your question: the answers is yes. Adjust your `php.ini include_path` to reflect the location of the Zend Framework Library:

`include_path=".;C:\Zend\ZendServer\bin\pear;C:\Zend\ZendServer\share\ZendFramework\library;"`

This is a windows example but a *nix example would be very similar.

Comment: In local its working i need to check it in dev environment....i hope it will works in dev enviroment also